# Listening radio with Mplayer in terminal

Tags: mplayer, internet-radio

I found out that listening to radio in terminal using "mplayer url" is much better than any software around, but after a while, terminal prints out a message saying *low on cache*.

How can I increase the cache in the terminal? Is it possible to free the used cache periodically while listening to the radio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set mplayer's cache with `-cache` argument on command line as well as specifying the initial cache fill before playback with '-cache-min'.

Try:

```
$ mplayer -cache 8192 -cache-min 80 <url>
```

p.s. 8192 should be enough, however, you can increase that number according to your needs. Note that the initial cache fill *without* the '-cache-min' option is only 20%.

Comment: My edit adds in the -cache-min option and brief explanatory note...

Answer (score 0):

To listen Internet-Radio from a terminal I would recommend [pyradio](http://www.coderholic.com/pyradio/)

As far as I know it uses mplayer and vlc in the background but has a really nice command-line interface.