# How to listen radio from terminal?

Tags: command-line, internet-radio

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

While seeing around here i have gone through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189440/listening-radio-with-mplayer-in-terminal)  But it didnt seems to be work with me . Here is my trail .

```
raja@badfox:~$ mplayer www.live365.com
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing www.live365.com.
File not found: 'www.live365.com'
Failed to open www.live365.com.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Its looks like some background work needed .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## mplayer

Try this.

```
mplayer http://80.237.154.83:8120
```

The IP-address of an online radio station can be found over at [**Xat radio search**](https://www.streamfinder.com/internet-radio-search/term/xat/).

My result :

[image]

### mplayer in IPv4 networks

**If your router only works with IPv4,** you will need to add the option `-prefer-ipv4`. More recent `mplayer` versions require this.

```
mplayer -prefer-ipv4 http://80.237.154.83:8120
```

Comment: Awesome man , may i have list of good radios ?

Comment: I donno man. I like english slow rock, oldies 80's 90's. Dont have idea whit yours ;) Btw try look at this site http://ipmusic.rad.io/

Comment: Defcon Hacker Radio: http://sfstream1.somafm.com:6200/

Comment: @penreturns Is it  possible to play the radio and record it at the same time?

Comment: @Sigur : I've never try this before but you can have a look at this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/291910/how-to-capture-desktop-sounds-pulse-audio-output-from-avconv

Comment: Usually xatworld and radiopecs intern. work, but not now. There is a server error. Any alternatives? The links by moewe are neither working with mplayer. My upload bandwith is only 0,01 Mbit/s, maybe this is the cause. Error by Radio Pecs: ICY-Server return 'Service Forbidden'
No stream found to handle url http://80.237.154.83:8120

Comment: works for 16.04, too.

Comment: Radio Pecs is not working anymore.

Comment: ```MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing http://-----.net:80/live.
Resolving ------.net for AF_INET...
Connecting to server -----.net[---.---.---.---]: 80...
Resolving -----.net for AF_INET...
Connecting to server -----.net[---.---.---.---]: 80...

Cache size set to 320 KBytes
Cache fill:  8.74% (28631 bytes)   

libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3```

Comment: @aderchox same failure here.

Answer (score 25):

## Using VLC from the command line

As usual, VLC does it all. Use `cvlc` to run VLC on the command line.

```
cvlc http://80.237.154.83:8120
cvlc us.darkmatter.aac.48k.m3u
```

VLC can also be invoked with a `ncurses` interface, as follows:

```
$ nvlc http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/CKFRAM.pls
```

or

```
$ vlc -I curses http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/CKFRAM.pls
```

Hit the <kbd>H</kbd> key for the much needed help.

Here is a screenshot of `nvlc` with a music playlist:

[image: nvlc]

## mplayer in IPv4 networks

**If your router only works with IPv4,** you will need to add the option `-prefer-ipv4`. More recent `mplayer` versions require this.

```
mplayer -prefer-ipv4 http://80.237.154.83:8120
```

See below to read how to use `mplayer` with `.m3u` and `.pls` streams.

## cmus also opens .m3u and .pls streams

Unlike `mplayer`, **[`cmus`](https://cmus.github.io/) also knows to open `.m3u` and `.pls` streams.** This means less digging or "background work" to extract the stream URL from those files.

Furthermore, `cmus` looks nice and offers several views, a file browser and many configuration settings. `cmus` is available from the standard Ubuntu repositories. To get up to speed with `cmus`, first read the tutorial by typing the following command:

```
$ man cmus-tutorial
```

[image: cmus]

## Open .m3u and .pls streams anyhow with mplayer

If you do not like `cmus`, or it is unavailable, `mplayer` *can* be made to do the same. For that purpose, I wrote the following `mplay` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
URL=$(grep -m 1 --null http "$1" |sed s/^.*http/http/ |tr -d '\r')
mplayer -prefer-ipv4 "$URL"
```

To navigate between directories of `.m3u` and `.pls` files, one could use the CLI file browser `ranger`, configured to call the above script for these file types. The struggle of setting this up pays itself back by being the fastest access method. This is what I personally use in a daily setting.

[image: ranger]

## pyradio

Here is a nice write-up describing [`pyradio`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/build-your-own-internet-radio-receiver)

Note that `pyradio` can also be installed and found as follows:

```
$ pip3 install pyradio
$ sudo find / -iname pyradio
$ ~/.local/bin/pyradio
```

## moc

Then there is also [`moc`](http://moc.daper.net/about).
MOC (music on console) is a full-screen `ncurses` based console audio player.

[image: MOC]

Select a file from some directory using a menu similar to Midnight Commander, and MOC will start playing all files in this directory beginning from the chosen file. There is no need to create any playlists, even though MOC handles these as well.

## mp3blaster

More details about yet another CLI music player, `mp3blaster` can be found [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mp3blaster-music-player-for-terminal/)

```
$ sudo apt install mp3blaster
```

[image: mp3blaster]

Comment: cmus worked great for me. I just had to do `:add [your stream link]` once in the interface.

Comment: VLC's `ncurses` interface can display an object tree; presss (`x`).

Comment: Listening to radio, this works so far, but nothing else: `vlc -I curses http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/CKFRAM.pls`

Comment: `mp3blaster` and `moc` are not for radio which is the topic here.

Answer (score 8):

There is indeed some "background work" to be done.

First of all, you will need to get hold of a URL that points to a real stream and not just a site that offers internet radio listening. This is probably the hardest part. You can search the station's website or google if there are any streams for that particular station. The stream URL is not the URL of a player on the station's website.

A URL might look like this: `http://bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx` (BBC Radio 1) or `http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1_aaclca.pls` (BBC Radio 1, but a different URL) or `http://www.ndr.de/resources/metadaten/audio/m3u/ndrloop5.m3u` (N-Joy); it will (very likely) not look like `www.live365.com`.

All of the above may be played back easily using `mplayer -playlist "<your url>"`, if that does not work with your stream, you can try `mplayer "<your url>"`.

Comment: yeah seems like this is the hidden tricky

Answer (score 6):

You can try [moc](https://moc.daper.net/about).  MOC (music on console) is a console audio player for LINUX/UNIX designed to be powerful and easy to use.

Comment: Can you give an example with a url?

Answer (score 5):

First, if you do not include "http://", then mplayer will try to open a file called "www.live365.com".

```
mplayer http://www.live365.com
```

This, however, will fail as well, since `http://www.live365.com` is not an address of a stream that mplayer could play, but of a web page. With a flash player.

Short answer -- open the website in firefox or another browser and click on "play".

Comment: Thanks man but its not worked  http://pastebin.com/x2jE3RQB

Comment: Yes. I wrote "This, however, will fail as well". mplayer can read audio and video streams, not web pages -- see the answer above.

Comment: Yes January :p , you said true . i read half only .

Answer (score 3):

### Tera

I'm the author of [Tera](https://github.com/shinokada/tera), an interactive terminal music radio player.

- 27780+ radio stations powered by Radio Browser API.
- MPV, a free, open-source, and cross-platform media player.
- CRUD favorite lists.
- Play from a list
- Search radio station by tag, name, language, country code, state.
- Save a station to a list after playing.
- Delete a radio station from a list.
- I feel lucky menu.
- Gist upload.

#### Installation

Either you clone the repo, use HomeBrew, install via deb package, or you can use [Awesome package manager](https://github.com/shinokada/awesome).

#### Usage

After installing Tera, you just need to run `tera` to run the program.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

You can find [more details here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/discover-rejuvenate-your-music-library-with-command-line-f3268db67bba). Other options [here](https://www.tecmint.com/command-line-music-players-for-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-1552071).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.   What I've done to get access to streams via command line is use the 'view source' to get the url of the stream.

For example, http://www.francebleu.fr/player opens in a browser and has buttons to play and stop etc.  Then I right-click and select 'view source' and another page opens.  I searched for mp3, (or you can search for "http://"), somewhere in there you'll find the link that is actually being used.  In the example here, it turned out to be sort of hidden...

{"mp3":"http://mp3.live.tv-radio.com/fbidf/all/fbidfhautdebit.mp3"}

But from that I got the link by removing the forward slashes. Thus finally, from the command line I execute "mplayer http://mp3.live.tv-radio.com/fbidf/all/fbidfhautdebit.mp3" and mplayer can process that stream.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Today I as looking for the same thing as the OP, and found an option I cannot believe is not listed here. **If you're interested in a music player server** which can run on the background and receive commands from any of many compatible clients, you could be interested in

## mpd

With an incredibly generic name, [Music Player Daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon) (mpd) is a server (so it runs in the background) that takes commands from client applications like the analogously named **mpc**. Both mpd and mpc are exclusively command line applications, but if you like a little GUI to go with your CLI, you can use clients for mpd such as [Ario](https://ario-player.sourceforge.net/).

Personally, I host an instance of MPD on a Raspberry Pi on my LAN, I connect a speaker to it, and I can SSH into it to control my music or use a  client like Ario from my PC to control it (also remotely).

I only discovered this today so pardon if this answer lacks depth. [The Arch Wiki page I linked](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon) will do a much better job than me in answering your questions about mpd though.

Answer (score 0):

`www.live365.com` is not the correct address of the radio stream, it is just an website address.

www.live365.com doesn't provide such addresses, radios there are meant to be played in the internet browser.

There are different ways to get the proper radio stream address. - Some radios stations list them themselves - like [FIP](https://www.fip.fr/comment-ecouter-fip).

But once you have chosen your preferred radio you need to get its streaming address. How to do that cannot be answered but on a per-case basis. There are websites that list radio stations and provide their streaming address, sometimes as a playlist file, for example http://www.listenlive.eu/. The playlist file contains links to the actual stream. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090879/4098390).

(I am trying to get more info in terminal on the playing song - so I have posted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457787/32012).)

---

Mpv also works, as a replacement of mplayer.

In terminal:

`mpv http://etcetcetc...`

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I guess the proper title of the above question is ""How to get the correct radio stream address in order to play it in terminal with mplayer?"

Comment: @DavidFoerster - can't you remove your delete vote?

Answer (score 0):

## mpv

[mpv](https://mpv.io/) is a video player based on MPlayer/mplayer2.

### Installation

```
apt-get install mpv
```

(tested on Ubuntu 20.04)

### Usage

See the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/mpv.1.html) and play a webradio stream like:

```bash
mpv https://www.ndr.de/resources/metadaten/audio/aac/ndrblue.m3u
```

It shows icy/shoutcast headers like (artist and title):

```
Playing: https://www.ndr.de/resources/metadaten/audio/aac/ndrblue.m3u
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
AO: [coreaudio] 48000Hz stereo 2ch floatp
A: 00:00:01 / 00:00:12 (16%) Cache: 10s/197KB
File tags:
 icy-title: Matt Simons - In Case You Missed It
A: 00:00:51 / 00:01:02 (82%) Cache: 10s/211KB
```