# Finding a stream in a radio.com URL

Tags: stream

Has anyone been able to play a radio.com radio station? I cannot locate a "stream" in this URL:

http://player.radio.com/player/RadioPlayer.php?version=1.2.13935&station=2108

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. [**This**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193737/how-to-listen-radio-from-terminal/193749#193749) may help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use Chrome developer tools>Network tab and load the page.  Once the music starts playing let it go for a while.  Once it starts you should see one element continue to load, that's the stream.

Highlight a section of the Network graph with only the streaming url visible and then it will be listed in the text box below.

Answer (score 0):

some sites dont give stream url. you need to go to offical page of radio stations and getting stream url in there .
explam : you cant get lastfm stream url in this page but you can get it on [last.fm](http://www.last.fm)

Comment: Yeah I'm getting that picture I was hoping there might be a way to "detect" the stream somehow.