# How to capture desktop sounds (Pulse Audio output) from avconv?

Tags: pulseaudio, avconv

I've tried :

> avconv -f alsa -i pulse recod.wav

..but it doesn't capture anything.
Have any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax to invoke **avconv** is nicely explained in the [manpage for avconv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/avconv.1.html). From audio recordings the following options are available:

`-f:` Force input or output file format.
`-i:` input file name

To record from ALSA we need the format to be `alsa`, and the input depends on the device we record (usually this will be the `defualt` device). Then your command should be as follows:

```
avconv -f alsa -i default record.wav
```

To simply record from an ALSA device we may consider using the more basic command line tool [arecord](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/aplay.1.html). This gives the following example command for a 10 second (`-d`) recording in cd quality (`-f`) in wav codec (`-t`):

```
arecord -d 10 -f cd -t wav -D copy record.wav
```

To be able to record from  an output sink, we may have to choose a **duplex** audio profile in *"Sound Settings --> Hardware*":

[image]

Unfortunately In >= 13.04 the hardware configuration was removed from the sound settings. To have access to advanced device configurations we need to install and run [**pavucontrol**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]. The duplex profile can then be selected in the *Configuration* tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but **avconv -f pulse -i default record.wav** doesn't work for me..Terminal output hilights this: **[pulse @ 0x1dfad60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate**  and I end up with a 34KB small wav file..

Comment: With ALSA, I'm having 3.8MB file, but there is nothing in it.. just an empty clip. :(

Comment: Ohmy god! I don't have a hardware tab like yours!... I do have an option to change profile in output tab...but there's no Duplex. I've only got Analog stereo output.... I'm on Raring Ringtail..

Comment: Duplex is important if you want to listen to what you record otherwise other settings would work as well for pure recording. I wrote a huge how-to on http://meshfields.de/audio-stream-recording-linux-avconv/

Comment: Launch `arecord` and, while recording, go in Volume Control `Recoding` tab. Here, you can change the default recording source, that will be used by further `arecord` invocations. Also, to avoid system volume change impact, open `Pulse Audio Preferences` app, go in `Simultaneous output` tab and enable the virtual device.